# Improving speed of for loop - basketball context, estimating whose on the court

Tags: r

This question is relating to a piece of R code I am trying to optimize for my sports job. The context is basketball for any sports fans out there. My task is to use the following dataframe of plays and player IDs to estimate who is on the basketball court at any time (5 players). The data dataframe corresponds with one basketball game. Therefore the dataset I'm working with is data from one basketball game, broken down by each playtype. There are about 10 unique player IDs for a basketball team. I have below some workable data that will work with the code:

```
team1 = c(76580, 76584, 76593, 76586, 76583, 76585, 76588, 76596, 76582, 76592, 76589, 76587)

data = structure(list(Tag_ID = c(69, 65, 74, 113, 64, 74, 77, 97, 64, 
74, 80, 85, 67, 74, 86, 117, 73, 91, 64, 74, 71, 82, 83, 107, 
63, 95, 63, 90, 64, 74, 77, 85, 67, 74, 77, 85, 67, 74, 71, 89, 
64, 74, 87, 64, 74, 78, 97, 64, 74, 88, 64, 74, 87, 64, 74, 88, 
64, 70, 77, 85, 67, 74, 77, 85, 67, 73, 78, 97, 64, 70, 92, 64, 
74, 77, 85, 67, 74, 80, 97, 64, 70, 71, 92, 64, 74, 78, 97, 64, 
74, 78, 82, 67, 85, 74, 72, 78, 86, 117, 74, 72, 80, 85, 67, 
73, 92, 64, 74, 101, 63, 90, 63, 90, 63, 90, 64, 74, 97, 64, 
74, 77, 97, 64, 74, 89, 64, 74, 91, 64, 74, 77, 83, 112, 64, 
74, 80, 85, 67, 74, 99, 69, 64, 74, 78, 97, 64, 74, 77, 67, 67, 
74, 80, 67, 67, 74, 86, 117, 73, 92, 64, 74, 111, 64, 74, 77, 
83, 82, 67, 67, 74, 80, 85, 67, 74, 88, 64, 74, 107, 63, 90, 
63, 81, 97, 64, 74, 78, 86, 117, 74, 89, 64, 74, 80, 85, 67, 
74, 77, 83, 80, 85, 67, 73, 80, 83, 109, 63, 95, 63, 90, 64, 
74, 71, 92, 64, 74, 72, 107, 63, 95, 63, 90, 64, 74, 92, 64, 
74, 82, 85, 67, 74, 82, 83, 106, 63, 90, 64, 74, 77, 85, 67, 
74, 77, 83, 113, 64, 74, 71, 114, 64, 74, 80, 83, 106, 63, 81, 
97, 64, 73, 97, 64, 74, 113, 64, 74, 82, 85, 67, 74, 80, 85, 
67, 73, 92, 69, 64, 74, 72, 91, 64, 74, 80, 85, 67, 73, 97, 64, 
74, 87, 64, 74, 80, 85, 67, 74, 77, 85, 67, 74, 88, 64, 70, 112, 
64, 74, 87, 64, 74, 98, 64, 74, 71, 92, 64, 74, 86, 117, 73, 
92, 64, 74, 71, 82, 97, 64, 74, 78, 97, 64, 76, 86, 117, 73, 
107, 63, 90, 63, 90, 64, 74, 78, 97, 64, 74, 80, 83, 105, 63, 
90, 67, 74, 92, 64, 74, 86, 117, 73, 88, 64, 74, 72, 91, 64, 
74, 97, 64, 74, 86, 117, 74, 87, 64, 74, 71, 100, 63, 90, 64, 
74, 88, 64, 70, 77, 97, 64, 74, 87, 64, 74, 101, 63, 95, 63, 
95, 63, 81, 85, 67, 74, 99, 69, 64, 74, 82, 85, 67, 74, 87, 64, 
74, 86, 117, 73, 92, 64, 74, 87, 64, 74, 97, 64, 74, 77, 85, 
67, 74, 106, 63, 90, 64, 74, 88, 64, 76, 72, 92, 64, 74, 72, 
82, 83, 88, 64, 74, 82, 85, 67, 74, 87, 64, 74, 78, 97, 64, 74, 
86, 117, 73, 107, 63, 95, 63, 81, 85, 67, 74, 72, 92, 64, 74, 
80, 85, 67, 74, 80, 85, 67, 74, 88, 64, 74, 77, 85, 67, 74, 71, 
78, 86, 117, 74, 82, 83, 82, 110, 64, 74, 78, 117, 74, 82, 110, 
64, 70, 91, 64, 74, 88, 63, 81, 85, 67, 74, 97, 64, 74, 99), 
    Tag_ID_Play = c("New Period", "Jumpball", "Halfcourt", "Violation", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Steal", "Steal", 
    "Fastbreak", "Jumper Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Left", 
    "Layup Miss", "ORB", "Shoot Foul Layup Miss", "FT Attempt", 
    "Non-Last FT Miss", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Drive Left", "Dunk Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Deflection", 
    "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "3pt Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", 
    "Baseline", "3pt Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Fastbreak", "Deflection", "OOB", "Inbounds", 
    "Baseline", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "OOB", "Inbounds", 
    "Baseline", "Drive Left", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Deflection", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Deflection", 
    "Layup Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Drive Right", "Deflection", 
    "Steal", "Steal", "Halfcourt", "Drive Right", "Jumper Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Fastbreak", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Shoot Foul 3pt Miss", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "FT Attempt", 
    "FT Make", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", "OOB", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Dunk Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", "ORB", "Tipin Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", 
    "Period Ends Play", "New Period", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Deflection", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", 
    "Steal", "Steal", "Fastbreak", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Timeout", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "ORB", "Layup Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Shoot Foul Layup Miss", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "FT Attempt", 
    "Last FT Miss", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Deflection", 
    "Steal", "Steal", "Halfcourt", "Dunk Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", "ORB", 
    "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Fastbreak", "Jumper Miss", 
    "ORB", "Shoot Foul Tipin Miss", "FT Attempt", "Non-Last FT Miss", 
    "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Left", 
    "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Right", "Shoot Foul Layup Miss", 
    "FT Attempt", "Non-Last FT Miss", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Layup Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Layup Miss", "ORB", 
    "Shoot Foul Layup Make", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "ORB", "Violation", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Left", 
    "Charge", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "ORB", 
    "Shoot Foul Layup Make", "FT Attempt", "Last FT Miss", "OOB", 
    "Inbounds", "Fastbreak", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Violation", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Layup Miss", "DRB", 
    "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Fastbreak", 
    "Layup Make", "New Period", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Right", 
    "Jumper Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "DRB", 
    "DRB", "Fastbreak", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", 
    "3pt Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", 
    "Baseline", "Tipin Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Other End", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Drive Left", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Steal", 
    "Steal", "Fastbreak", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Drive Left", "Layup Miss", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Deflection", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Sideline", "Steal", "Steal", 
    "Fastbreak", "Shoot Foul Layup Miss", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", 
    "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Deflection", 
    "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "ORB", "Shoot Foul Jumper Miss", 
    "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Layup Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Steal", "Steal", "Fastbreak", "Def Foul", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Right", "Jumper Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Steal", "Steal", 
    "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Drive Left", 
    "Shoot Foul 3pt Make", "FT Attempt", "FT Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", "Baseline", "3pt Miss", 
    "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Shoot Foul 3pt Miss", "FT Attempt", "Non-Last FT Miss", 
    "FT Attempt", "Non-Last FT Miss", "FT Attempt", "Last FT Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Period Ends Play", "New Period", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Layup Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", 
    "3pt Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Steal", "Steal", "Fastbreak", 
    "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "OOB", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "3pt Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Shoot Foul Layup Make", "FT Attempt", 
    "FT Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", 
    "Sideline", "Drive Right", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "Drive Right", "Layup Miss", "ORB", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Layup Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "3pt Make", 
    "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Deflection", "OOB", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Steal", "Steal", "Fastbreak", "Shoot Foul Layup Miss", 
    "FT Attempt", "Non-Last FT Miss", "FT Attempt", "Last FT Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Drive Right", "Layup Make", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Jumper Miss", 
    "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", 
    "3pt Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "Drive Left", "Deflection", 
    "Steal", "Steal", "Halfcourt", "Layup Miss", "ORB", "Layup Miss", 
    "Tie Up", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Deflection", "Steal", 
    "Halfcourt", "Layup Miss", "Tie Up", "Inbounds", "Baseline", 
    "Jumper Make", "Inbounds", "Halfcourt", "Def Foul", "FT Attempt", 
    "Last FT Miss", "DRB", "DRB", "Halfcourt", "OOB", "Inbounds", 
    "Halfcourt", "Period Ends Play"), player_id = c(NA, 76580L, 
    NA, 76584L, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, 76607L, 76607L, 
    NA, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76580L, NA, NA, 76600L, 76600L, 76607L, 
    76607L, 76607L, NA, 76607L, 76607L, NA, NA, 76586L, 76599L, 
    76599L, NA, 76607L, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76583L, 76580L, NA, 
    NA, 76599L, NA, NA, 76599L, 76583L, NA, NA, 76586L, NA, NA, 
    76607L, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, 76583L, 76607L, 76607L, NA, 
    76607L, 76584L, 76584L, NA, 76605L, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, NA, 
    NA, 76607L, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76580L, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, 
    76583L, NA, NA, 76586L, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, 76605L, 76586L, 
    76586L, NA, 76586L, 76599L, 76599L, 76599L, NA, 76599L, 76607L, 
    76584L, 76584L, NA, 76586L, NA, NA, 76599L, 76599L, 76599L, 
    76599L, 76599L, 76599L, 76599L, NA, NA, 76586L, NA, NA, 76599L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76585L, NA, NA, 76607L, NA, NA, 76584L, 76588L, 
    76588L, NA, NA, 76603L, 76583L, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    76593L, NA, NA, NA, 76607L, 76580L, 76580L, NA, 76593L, 76607L, 
    76607L, NA, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    76607L, 76605L, 76605L, 76596L, 76596L, NA, 76580L, 76607L, 
    76607L, NA, 76580L, NA, NA, 76607L, 76607L, 76607L, 76607L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76580L, NA, NA, 
    76607L, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76593L, 76583L, 76583L, 76605L, 
    76605L, NA, 76603L, 76607L, 76607L, 76607L, NA, 76607L, 76607L, 
    NA, NA, 76583L, 76583L, NA, NA, 76603L, 76603L, 76603L, NA, 
    76603L, 76603L, NA, NA, 76580L, NA, NA, 76607L, 76583L, 76583L, 
    NA, 76583L, 76580L, 76580L, 76580L, 76580L, NA, NA, 76605L, 
    76583L, 76583L, NA, 76580L, 76593L, 76583L, NA, NA, 76605L, 
    76605L, NA, NA, 76583L, 76585L, 76583L, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76607L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, 76605L, 76605L, NA, 
    76603L, 76588L, 76588L, NA, 76585L, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, 76580L, 
    NA, NA, 76599L, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, 76600L, 
    NA, NA, 76586L, 76599L, 76599L, NA, 76599L, 76593L, 76593L, 
    NA, 76599L, NA, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, 76607L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76586L, 76586L, NA, NA, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76584L, NA, 
    NA, 76603L, 76603L, NA, NA, NA, 76586L, NA, NA, NA, 76586L, 
    76586L, NA, 76586L, 76586L, 76586L, 76586L, 76586L, NA, NA, 
    76583L, NA, NA, NA, 76607L, 76606L, 76606L, 76606L, 76606L, 
    76596L, NA, 76596L, NA, NA, 76593L, 76593L, NA, 76607L, NA, 
    NA, 76584L, 76586L, NA, NA, 76601L, NA, NA, 76603L, 76603L, 
    NA, 76601L, NA, NA, 76584L, 76593L, 76593L, 76593L, NA, NA, 
    76593L, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, 76601L, 
    76601L, NA, 76601L, NA, 76601L, NA, 76596L, 76596L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76606L, 76596L, 76596L, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, 76593L, 
    76593L, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, 76607L, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, 
    76607L, 76582L, 76582L, NA, 76596L, 76596L, 76596L, NA, NA, 
    76582L, NA, NA, 76599L, 76599L, NA, NA, 76584L, 76584L, 76596L, 
    76599L, NA, NA, 76588L, 76603L, 76603L, NA, 76607L, NA, NA, 
    76602L, NA, NA, NA, 76602L, 76602L, NA, 76603L, 76603L, NA, 
    76603L, NA, 76585L, 76585L, NA, 76584L, 76585L, NA, NA, 76599L, 
    76582L, 76582L, NA, 76580L, 76602L, 76602L, NA, 76582L, NA, 
    NA, 76605L, 76592L, 76592L, NA, 76586L, 76604L, 76604L, 76604L, 
    NA, 76606L, 76606L, 76606L, 76606L, NA, NA, 76606L, 76606L, 
    NA, 76606L, 76606L, NA, NA, 76602L, NA, NA, 76602L, 76589L, 
    NA, 76602L, 76602L, NA, 76601L, NA, NA, NA), player2_id = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76607L, 
    76607L, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, NA, 
    NA, 76607L, NA, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, 76603L, NA, NA, 76603L, 
    NA, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76607L, NA, NA, NA, 76605L, 76593L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76585L, 76585L, 76585L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76584L, 
    NA, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, 76580L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76603L, 76603L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76607L, 
    NA, NA, 76596L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76606L, 76606L, 
    76606L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76586L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76602L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76605L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    76583L, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, 76600L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 76605L, 76605L, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, NA, 76584L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, 76600L, 76600L, NA, 76607L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76607L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76588L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, 76600L, 76600L, NA, 76586L, 
    NA, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, 76583L, NA, 
    76607L, NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76606L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76586L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76596L, NA, NA, NA, 76583L, NA, 
    NA, 76607L, 76607L, NA, 76593L, NA, NA, 76601L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76596L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76602L, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, NA, 76580L, 76580L, NA, 
    76580L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76584L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76599L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 76586L, 76586L, 76586L, NA, 76587L, NA, NA, 76592L, NA, 
    NA, 76592L, 76592L, NA, 76589L, 76589L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    76589L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), indicator_newperiod = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Tag_ID", 
"Tag_ID_Play", "player_id", "player2_id", "indicator_newperiod"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 46L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 89L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 
161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 
172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 201L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 
205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 
227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 
238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 244L, 243L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 249L, 
248L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 
260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 274L, 
270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 
282L, 284L, 283L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 
293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 298L, 297L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 
304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 
315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 502L, 503L, 
504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 
331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 
342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 
353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 
364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 
375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 
386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 
397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 
408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 
419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 
430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 
441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 
452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 
463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 
474L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 
485L, 486L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 
492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L))
```

next, below is the on_court dataframe I am attempting to fill up (not filled in, only initialized with the default NAs). the number of rows of the on_court dataframe is the same as the number of rows of the data dataframe. I am effectively guessing who is on court for each and every play. once filled in, each row of the on_court dataframe will have 5 player_IDs.

```
head(on_court, n = 20)
#    P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
# 1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 2  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 3  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 5  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 6  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 8  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 11 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 16 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 17 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 18 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 19 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
# 20 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

using the two player ID columns, which correspond to the players that were involved in each play, makes it possible to guess who's on the court using the following strategy - I simply assume that the 5 players who most recently were tagged in an event are on the court. it is important to note that the data dataframe has all of the plays of the basketball game in order, which makes this approach possible.

My code uses a front and back counter (i and j, respectively) that always tries to find the 5 player IDs that appeared most recently in the basketball game, and assumes those are the five players on the court. This particular game has 514 plays / events / nrow(data). Since there is a maximum of 2 player IDs per play, that means I have 1028 player IDs to work with. My current code iterates over these 1028 player IDs, and looks like this. this code should be able to be run in connection with the list and dataframe from above:

```
# 1 - Before the for loop
# 1.a create custom rounding function that rounds 0.5 upwards
round2 = function(x, n) {
  posneg = sign(x)
  z = abs(x)*10^n
  z = z + 0.5
  z = trunc(z)
  z = z/10^n
  z*posneg
}

#1.b create on_court dataframe
on_court = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = nrow(data)))
names(on_court) = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5")

# 1.c combine the two player ID columns into one column
player_ids_unlisted = as.vector(t(data[, c("player_id", "player2_id")]))
K = 0.525

j = 1
# begin the for loop
for(i in 1:length(player_ids_unlisted)) {
  # dividing the counter in half gives the play number 
  i_2 = round2(i/2, 0)
  j_2 = round2(j/2, 0)

  # if the playtype is 'new period', bring the back counter j to match the front counter i. 
  # at the start of a new period of the game, this resets who we think is on the court
  if (data$indicator_newperiod[i_2] == 1) {
    j = i
    j_2 = i_2
  }

  # unique player_IDs in range of events / counters, 
  # then remove NA player IDs,
  # then filter the list by players only on team 1  
  uq_players = unique(player_ids_unlisted[j:i])
  uq_players = uq_players[!is.na(uq_players)]
  uq_players = uq_players[uq_players %in% team1]

  # length of unique player_ID list  
  uq_span = length(uq_players)                    

  # early in the game, if 5 unique player_IDs have yet to appear, then pass
  if(uq_span < 5) {                           
      next                                         
  }

  #  if we have exactly 5 players identified, set them as the players on court
  else if(uq_span == 5) {                     
    on_court[i_2, 1:5] = uq_players
  }

  else {                                        
    # as the i counter increments, eventually the list of unique players will reach 6 players. 
    # when that is the case, I increment the back counter j until we get back down to 5 players 
    # (effectively removing the player who hasn't been tagged in an event for the most time from the list of 
    # players on court). Then I update whose on court again.
    while (uq_span > 5) {
      j = j + 1

      # again, find IDs, remove NAs, filter by team 1
      uq_players = unique(player_ids_unlisted[j:i])    
      uq_players = uq_players[!is.na(uq_players)]
      uq_players = uq_players[uq_players %in% team1]

      uq_span = length(uq_players)
    }

    # this j_2 is the play index that the player we're subbing out last was tagged in an event
    # mid_idx is the index between when the j_2 player_ID was last in an event and the new i_2 player_ID was just in an event
    j_2 = round2(j/2, 0)
    mid_idx = round2((i_2*K + j_2*(1-K)), 0)

    # update with this lineup going all the way back to the mid_idx play index 
    uq_players_df = as.data.frame(t(uq_players))
    count = i_2 - mid_idx + 1

    # and finally update the on court dataframe 
    uq_players_df = uq_players_df[rep(row.names(uq_players_df), count), ]
    on_court[mid_idx:i_2, 1:5] = uq_players_df    
  }

  # for the earliest plays of each half, before 5 player IDs were identified
  # we left NAs in the on_court dataframe for whose on court. 
  # once we have 5 player IDs, drag them up to fill in the earlier NAs
  this_row_NA = ifelse(is.na(on_court$P1[i_2]), 1, 0)
  last_row_NA = ifelse(is.na(on_court$P1[(i_2-1)]), 1, 0)
  if (last_row_NA > this_row_NA) {
    NA_plays = which(is.na(on_court$P1))
    start = min(NA_plays)
    on_court[start:(i_2-1), 1:5] = on_court[i_2, 1:5]
  }
}
```

and that's my code. It is a bit complicated because the counters i and j count up to 1028 even though there are only 514 plays, and so I have to use the i_2 and j_2 counters when indexing play numbers. It is complicated further by my introduction of the mid_idx counter, which I use to sub players into the game before they are actually tagged in a play. The main issue though, what I am looking for help with, is that this is being done entirely in a big for loop with a few if cases, and currently takes too much time to run (~0.50 seconds per game). I need this code to run over tens of thousands of basketball games, and would prefer for this code to run in 1/10 to 1/100 (may not be possible). Vectorizing the code, or using apply functions, instead of the large for loop would probably make the code run faster but I have struggled to think how it could be implemented. I have been working hard on improving code performance this summer too, and working to improve a piece of code like this is both difficult but useful. Any thoughts would be appreciated on how I can speed this up.

Thanks very much!

Comment: From what I see in your code, if `i` starts at 1, and `i_2 = round(i/2, 0)` then `i_2` is 0, and `if (data$indicator_newperiod[i_2] == 1) ` will give an error. Could you maybe post a reproducible example (with data, use `dput()`)?

Comment: Wouldn't your `on_court` dataframe contain distinct play rows? Not the same nrows as `data` dataframe, otherwise you will return NAs?

Comment: my bad. I have a custom round function that rounds 0.5 up to 1. I will edit post with the function, and with some full data too, thanks

Comment: okay edit made, I think you can just copy paste the dataframes and code now (never heard of dput() before, so let me know if it doesn't work). also, the NAs get removed from data, which I forgot to include earlier but updated now.

Comment: Your `dput()` is not quite working. I believe you cut off some items in post. There might need to be a `class="data.frame"` indicator at end. Also, you did not answer my above question. Should not `on_court` be less rows as it should represent distinct plays?

Comment: dput() for the data dataframe is updated

on_court is the same number of rows as data, yes. In data, each row corresponds to a play in the basketball game. For the plays / rows in data that do not have any players tagged in it, I take that as the lineup on court hasn't changed. Will probably be easier to follow once code is reproducable, which it hopefully is now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you have to iterate over every row of your dataframe. However, I think your algorithm to determine the 5 players on court can be done easier. In my solution I only iterate over the number of rows of the data and I use a vector of length 5 to control the players on the field:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {

    # reset players on court
    if(i == 1 | data$indicator_newperiod[i] == 1) poc = numeric(5)

    # Add new Player1 (if any)
    if(!is.na(data$player_id[i]) && !(data$player_id[i] %in% poc)) {
        poc[1:4] = poc[2:5]
        poc[5] = data$player_id[i]
    }   

    # Add new Player2 (if any)
    if(!is.na(data$player2_id[i]) && !(data$player2_id[i] %in% poc)) {
        poc[1:4] = poc[2:5]
        poc[5] = data$player2_id[i]
    }

    # fill result dataframe
    on_court[i, 1:5] = poc
}
```

for filling up the periods after breaks I iterate backwards:

```
# Filling up players on court, after break
for(i in nrow(on_court):2) {
    if(on_court$P1[i-1] == 0) on_court[i-1, 1:5] = on_court[i, 1:5]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I watched and manually tagged on court for two games so i have two games to check the accuracy of whose on court. I can run with your suggestion and see if it's more accurate than mine